# How do I select unique pairs of rows from a table at random?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables like these:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE pairs (
    person_a_id INT,
    person_b_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_a_id) REFERENCES people(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_b_id) REFERENCES people(id) 
)
```

I want to select pairs of people at random from the people table, and after selecting them I add the randomly select pair to the pairs table.  person_a_id always refers to the person with the lower id of the pair (since the order of the pair is not relevant).

The thing is that I never want to select the same pair twice, so I need to check the pairs table before I return my randomly selected pair.

Is it possible to do this using just a single SQL query in a reasonably efficient and elegant manner?

(I'm doing this using the Java Persistence API, but hopefully I'll be able to translate any answers into JPA code)

Comment: It might be doable, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: I don't see how this will be possible in a set-based approach. I can solve it using a cursor (so it can be accomplished in a single stored procedure). The biggest obstacle is that your selection pool must decrease for each random pair you add to the pairs table.

Comment: This is where MySQL's lack of support for check constraints hurts. This is a situation where having a check that forces person_a_id < person_b_id would be quite useful. You should however at least put a unique constraint on the pairs table.

Comment: @Mark Byers - Sorting isn't really the issue here. Certainly MySQL does not rock with respect to data integrity in this case. Only with a trigger could you enforce that A < B and guarantee that you do not reuse pairs at the database level.

Comment: Something else that is not mentioned is "how random?". Technically, a cross join of the people table is "random"; just not particularly difficult to predict. What does the distribution have to look like? Is there a limit on membership in pairs? E.g., can person_id = 42 be in every pair? I think the best solution in this case would be to generate your randomization in Java while you log the pairs that are used and have the db act as a last line of protection against duplicates.

Comment: As for "how random", I'm sure ORDER BY RAND() should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a.id, b.id
from people1 a
inner join people1 b on a.id < b.id
where not exists (
    select *
    from pairs1 c
    where c.person_a_id = a.id
      and c.person_b_id = b.id)
order by a.id * rand()
limit 1;
```

`Limit 1` returns just one pair if you are "drawing lots" one at a time. Otherwise, up the limit to however many pairs you need.

The above query assumes that you can get

```
1 - 2
2 - 7
```

and that the pairing `2 - 7` is valid since it doesn't exist, even if 2 is featured again.  If you only want a person to feature in `only one` pair ever, then

```
select a.id, b.id
from people1 a
inner join people1 b on a.id < b.id
where not exists (
    select *
    from pairs1 c
    where c.person_a_id in (a.id, b.id))
  and not exists (
    select *
    from pairs1 c
    where c.person_b_id in (a.id, b.id))
order by a.id * rand()
limit 1;
```

If `multiple pairs` are to be generated in one single query, **AND** the destination table is still empty, you could use this single query.  Take note that `LIMIT 6` returns only 3 pairs.

```
select min(a) a, min(b) b
from
(
    select
      case when mod(@p,2) = 1 then id end a,
      case when mod(@p,2) = 0 then id end b,
      @p:=@p+1 grp
    from (
        select id
        from (select @p:=1) p, people1
        order by rand()
        limit 6
    ) x
) y
group by floor(grp/2)
```

Comment: This will return a randomly ordered list of all combinations. It will still need to be iterated. It is unsafe to use anything other than `LIMIT 1` because it's possible to pair the same person twice in a single iteration. EDIT: Your edit addresses this.

Comment: Add `INSERT INTO tbl` before the `SELECT`? What needs to be iterated? Is it SAME-PAIR or SAME-PERSON? Not clear if 1-2 and 2-7 `in the same query` is valid

Comment: @cyberwiki perhaps a vague question... If he wants to generate random pairs (as opposed to all possible pairs) then it must be iterated because `pairs` will be empty when you first look into it.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is there a reason you are referring to the tables as "people1" and "pairs1" rather than just "people" and "pairs"?

Comment: @sanity - Good question. Because I already have a "people" table and can't be bothered dropping it in my test db :) I normally post only tested code

Comment: cyberkiwi, I've asked a followup question which you may care to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833908/how-do-i-get-this-sql-query-to-output-two-rows-rather-than-two-fields

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be accomplished in a single-query set-based approach because your set will not have knowledge of what pairs are inserted into the pairs table.

Instead, you should loop

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM people 
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT person_a_id FROM pairs) 
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT person_b_id FROM pairs)
```

This will loop while there are unmatched people.
Then you should two random numbers from 1 to the `CNT(*)` of that table
which gives you the number of unmatched people... if you get the same number twice, roll again. (IF you're worried about this, randomize numbers from the two halves of the set... but then you're losing some randomness based on your sort criteria)

Pair those people.

Wash, rinse, repeat....
Your only "redo" will be when you generate the same random number twice... more likely as you get few people but still only a 25% chance at most (much better than 1/n^2)