# How do I get this SQL query to output two rows, rather than two fields?

Tags: mysql

Here is my SQL query, it produces a single result row, with two columns "lower", and "higher".  These correspond to the primary keys ("id") of rows in the Rankable table.

The purpose of the query is to select a random pair of Rankable rows, that isn't already present in the Comparison table (which contains all previous pairs).

What I need, however, is for this query to return the two Rankables as rows, not just the Rankable ids as fields in a single row.

This is the current query:

```
SELECT a.id AS lower, b.id AS higher
FROM Rankable a
INNER JOIN Rankable b on a.id < b.id
WHERE 
  a.category_id = ? AND b.category_id = ?
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Comparison c
    WHERE c.lower_id in (a.id, b.id))
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Comparison c
    WHERE c.higher_id IN (a.id, b.id))
ORDER BY a.id * rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sorry about the `PIVOT` recommendation.. I didn't notice your mysql tag... deleted my answer like 20 seconds after posting it but some ninja still got a downvote in :D

Comment: @Matthew PK I almost posted solution using `WITH` till I checked and found at MySQL doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this MySQL hacking..

```
select @a as one
from
(

    SELECT @a := a.id, @b := b.id
    FROM Rankable a
    INNER JOIN Rankable b on a.id < b.id
    WHERE 
      a.category_id = ? AND b.category_id = ?
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Comparison c
        WHERE c.lower_id in (a.id, b.id))
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Comparison c
        WHERE c.higher_id IN (a.id, b.id))
    ORDER BY a.id * rand()
    LIMIT 1
) SQ
union all
select @b
```

To join to the table to get all other columns:

```
select Rankable.*
from
(
    select 1 as Sort, @a as one
    from
    (

        SELECT @a := a.id, @b := b.id
        FROM Rankable a
        INNER JOIN Rankable b on a.id < b.id
        WHERE 
          a.category_id = ? AND b.category_id = ?
          AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Comparison c
            WHERE c.lower_id in (a.id, b.id))
          AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM Comparison c
            WHERE c.higher_id IN (a.id, b.id))
        ORDER BY a.id * rand()
        LIMIT 1
    ) SQ
    union all
    select 2, @b
) X
INNER JOIN Rankable ON Rankable.Id = X.one
ORDER BY X.Sort
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking forward to trying it.  Ugh, its a shame that you can't do something like this without hackery.  Makes you wonder if SQL is the "right way".

Comment: Though I gave the answer, sincerely advise you to look at just using the front end, which is trivial to process whether as 2 columns or 2 rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "front end"?  The reason I need it as two rows is so that it plays nice with the Java Persistence API.

Comment: Ah, just tried this query.  Actually - its not quite what I need.  Would it be possible for it to return the entire row from Rankable, rather than just the ids?  ie. similar to "SELECT * FROM Rankable;"

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 queries one for the lower and one for the higher ranks then union them together.
Create a static column with the rank to identify which is which. 'higher' or 'lower as rank

Comment: That sounds challenging, because we need to verify that the specific pair isn't present in the Comparison table, so we need both of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but I think this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM Rankable JOIN (
  SELECT a.id AS lower, b.id AS higher 
  FROM Rankable a 
  INNER JOIN Rankable b on a.id < b.id 
  WHERE    
    a.category_id = ? AND b.category_id = ?   
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM Comparison c
      WHERE c.lower_id in (a.id, b.id)
      )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM Comparison c
      WHERE c.higher_id IN (a.id, b.id)
      )
   ORDER BY a.id * rand() 
   ) AS rank_them
ON (Rankable.id = rank_them.higher OR Rankable.id = rank_them.lower)
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work, it returned 12 rows (there were 4 rows in Rankable, nothing in Comparison) :-(