# How can I randomly assign one user to another in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, random

I'm trying to write a sproc that will take a table of users and assign them to each other randomly with no duplicates and no one assigned to themselves.

The user table has an UserId column and a Username column. I have a separate table for storing the IDs. That table has a UserId column and an AssignedUserId column.

I used this snippet for randomly sorting rows:

```
SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS [RandomNumber]
```

When the code above is part of a select, it works fine. I'm just having a hard time thinking as a data set. I can work the problem row-by-row or in C#, but I'm hoping there's a SQL guru that can show me how to do this in a nice, efficient query.

Thanks!

Comment: Define no duplicates.  You want to assign (update) the AssignedUserId column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select unique pairs of rows from a table at random?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823208/how-do-i-select-unique-pairs-of-rows-from-a-table-at-random)

Comment: For no dups, I mean that each pairing should be unique and no one should get assigned to themselves.

Comment: @Pondlife you are correct! That is exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but not good practice on large tables, but with your table being so small this will work great.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (A1 INT, A2 INT)

INSERT INTO @A VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES(2, 2)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES(3, 3)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES(4, 4)
INSERT INTO @A VALUES(5, 5)

SELECT * FROM @A ORDER BY NEWID()

Result1: 
3   3
1   1
4   4
5   5
2   2

Result2:
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
1   1

Result3:
4   4
3   3
1   1
5   5
2   2

Result4:
3   3
5   5
1   1
4   4
2   2

Result5:
5   5
4   4
1   1
3   3
2   2
```

Comment: There should be less than 100 users if the system went live today. It is an internal application. The select using NEWID() I get. I can't wrap my mind around joining the table to itself or a temp table or whatever and get the server to figure out the pairs.

Comment: Can you post a sample?   Order By NewID() should work fine with such a small amount of data.  What is does is randomly orders each column, even if you have two columns.

Comment: I'm looking for results like this: 1 - 3, 2 - 4, 9 - 7, but not 3 - 3 or 1 - 2, 3 - 2 (2 shouldn't get paired twice).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an alternate solution I came up with in the mean time. I decided that the users are already in the system in random order, so maybe I should try a decoder-ring style approach. So, this code generates a shift value and then shifts the user IDs around. The select statement does the "wrap-around" with a formula. It's not completely random and it could use some polish, but this is what I have. The users probably won't perceive the lack of randomness. Thanks for the help!

```
DECLARE @people TABLE 
( 
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @people VALUES (1,'Matthew')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (2,'Mark')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (3,'Luke')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (4,'John')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (5,'Doug')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (6,'Jamie')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (7,'John')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (8,'Cameron')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (9,'Emily')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (10,'Tyler')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (11,'Todd')
INSERT INTO @people VALUES (12,'Kathryn')

DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;
DECLARE @MaxId INT;

SET @Lower = 1 -- The lowest record ID

SELECT @Upper = (MAX(Id) / 2) FROM @people -- select random int that is somewhere between 1 and half of max ID for shift
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM @people -- select the largest ID in the table

SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0) -- calculate a random number to shift IDs off by

SELECT id, ((id + @Random) % @MaxId) + 1, @Random
from @people
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to do this, but your randomly picking only the top half of the group.    "Upper-Lower-1" should be, just Upper, if you want to randomize everyone.