# Select unique pairs of users from a table at random

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to create random user pairs between our database users.

I have the following user table:

**Table: tbl_users**

```
user_id | name
--------+--------------
1       | Jay
2       | Ram
3       | John
4       | Kevin
5       | Jenny
6       | Tony
```

I want to generate a random result like this:

```
from_id | to_id
--------+---------
1       | 6 
5       | 3 
2       | 4
```

Can this be done in MySQL only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823208/how-do-i-select-unique-pairs-of-rows-from-a-table-at-random

Comment: Since you marked it with `php`: do that in php. It will be inefficient in mysql. Generate an array with your numbers 1...max, use e.g. [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shuffle.php) and use that array to fill your pairing table (1st value in the array is 1st `from_id`, 2nd value is 1st `to_id`, 3rd value is 2nd `from_id` and so on).

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare for comment, but i want random users pairing records from database. random pairing is easy to setup in php, but i want from database select query.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a duplicate of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823208/how-do-i-select-unique-pairs-of-rows-from-a-table-at-random), so the answer is there.

However, even if it is indeed possible in MySQL doing this there is not really recommended. PHP is a much better tool for handling this, as what you're doing is actually manipulating data as per some business rule. It'll be a lot easier to maintain by doing it in PHP, and I suspect that it'll be less resource-intensive as well.

A possible way to do this, which I'd prefer. Is to do a random sort in SQL, and then pair up two and two rows against each other. Something like this:

```
$grouping = {};
// Fetching both rows to ensure that we actually have an even number paired up.
while ($row = $res->fetch_array () && $row2 = $res->fetch_array ()) {
    $grouping[] = {$row['name'], $row2['name']};
}
```

If you want to allow for an unmatched user to be listed, simply move the second fetch to the inside of the loop. Then deal with the potentially missing result there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to generate your list:

```sql
select max(from_id) as from_id,
       max(to_id) as to_id
from (
  select 
    case when rownum mod 2 = 1 then user_id else null end as from_id,
    case when rownum mod 2 = 0 then user_id else null end as to_id,
    (rownum - 1) div 2 as pairnum
  from (
    select user_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum
    from 
      (select @rownum := 0) as init,
      (select user_id from tbl_user order by rand()) as randlist
  ) as randlistrownum
) as randlistpairs  
group by pairnum;
```

Step by step, this will:

- order the userlist in random order
- assign a rownumber to it (otherwise the order will have no meaning)
- assign two consecutive rows the same `pairnum` (`rownum = 1` and `rownum = 2` get the value `pairnum = 0`, the next two rows will get `pairnum = 1` and so on)
- the first row of these paired rows will get the values `from_id = user_id` and `to_id = null`, the other row will be `to_id = user_id` and `from_id = null`
- `group by` these pairs together to make them into one row
- if you have an odd number of users, one user will end up with `to_id = null`, because it has no partner

A little more compact if you prefer shorter code:

```sql
select max(case when rownum mod 2 = 1 then user_id else null end) as from_id,
       max(case when rownum mod 2 = 0 then user_id else null end) as to_id
from (
  select user_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum, (@rownum - 1) div 2 as pairnum
  from 
     (select @rownum := 0) as init,
     (select user_id from tbl_user order by rand()) as randlist
) as randlistpairs
group by pairnum;
```